# Lactofermenting fruits successfully

Tags: fermentation, lactofermentation

Always when I tried lactofermentation of fruits like pears, plums, or citrus fruits, they always turned bad. When letting them ferment less time, they were still not fermented at all or already gone bad. I tried up to 8% salt solution but they just turn bad and produce some form of alcohol. To be more specific, on top of the liquid appeared white blueish mold (possibly in some cases the white one that is not optimal but okay), but some parts of the fruits had some white mold on themselves, and they tasted repulsively like alcohol.

Can you ferment fruits at all, if yes how, what can I improve, what did you do?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "they just turned bad?"  What did you observe?

Comment: Now it's specified. Thanks

Comment: How are you storing them during fermentation? I saw Brad from Bon Appétit make fermented citrus fruit and he vaccuum sealed the salted fruit in a plastic bag. If you just leave them in a jar or similar, the air might be what's causing your problems.

Comment: That's a good point. I had them in a maison jar with air locks. But surely, in the beginning there is aire. Maybe I will try to cover it with oil, so that it is anerobic. Plastic is no option, it poisons food